# Is there a way to let shuffle.js recalculate it space?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, shuffle

I am currently using [shuffle.js](https://vestride.github.io/Shuffle/) and I am struggeling with its responsive space.

So I have 2 divs 1 is filled with filters that allow me to filter the products in my shuffle.js grid. The other div is the grid.

[This is when the filters are open](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9M99.png)

[This is when the filters are closed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/omXyR.png)

so how do I make it so it fits in the div? When I resize the window the items will recalculate and know that the width if the div is smaller. So on the butten press I need to have the window resized? but without refreshing? Is something like this possible?

This is the button script

```
  jQuery("#toggleButton").click(function () {
    var moreFiltersBox = $(".more_filters_box");
    var openSpan = $(".open");
    var closeSpan = $(".closes");

    if (moreFiltersBox.width() === 0) {
      moreFiltersBox.animate({ width: "25%" });
      openSpan.hide();
      closeSpan.show();
      
      
    } else {
      moreFiltersBox.animate({ width: "0" });
      openSpan.show();
      closeSpan.hide();
    }
  });
```

So I am trying to have the window resized without refreshing but there might be other ways that shufflejs offers but I am not able to find them.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use the update method mentioned in the API at [this link](https://vestride.github.io/Shuffle/docs/api)

> Repositions everything. Useful for when dimensions (like the window size) change.You may provide an options object containing the following properties

Comment: I added this to the button click code

    shuffleInstance.update({ 
        recalculateSizes: true,
        force: true,
    });

But It doesn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: Are you sure this section of code has been called?, if yes, use  a setTimeOut function to update after the animation is finished!

Comment: So I did that still doesn't seems to be working. I also added the code 

shuffleInstance.on(Shuffle.EventType.LAYOUT, () => {
  console.log('Things finished moving!');
});

So I know when the grid is moving. when I press the button is tells me its moving but it isn't

Comment: So i fixed it by executing the whole shuffle.js again each time I click on the button.